# MathJax broken after submitting an edit

Tags: bug, mathjax, editing

Recently, after I perform an edit, it seems the mathjax rendering takes more space than it is given, resulting with overlapping with the text after it. Example (from q10437, right after editing it):

[image]

Is this a known bug?

[After several refreshing, the problem disappeared, and now it looks good here. Firefox 19.0 on OS X].

Comment: Happens to me as well. Chrome 24.0 on OS X 10.6.8.

Comment: Has been happening for a long time. Reloading the page usually gets rid of the effect. You use the MathML-renderer? I use the HTML+CSS renderer, same effect.

Comment: I've seen MathJax go wrong after inline editing and other changes that don't fully reload the page such as live front page updates. A full reload (Shift+reload) always gets things right for me.

Comment: Yep, has been happening for a long time for me, and across the various SE sites that support MathJax. A simple reload (not even a full reload) works for me.

Comment: @Paresh That works for me too.